# Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol using PublicClient samples for ADAL

Tags: java, azure, active-directory, adal

I wanted to play around with [Microsoft Azure's Active Directory Library for Java](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java). After I pulled the code from github and importing to Eclipse as a maven project, building and executing the [PublicClient.java](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/blob/master/src/samples/public-client-app-sample/src/main/java/PublicClient.java) sample file, I get the following exception:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at src.main.java.PublicClient.getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials(PublicClient.java:36)
    at src.main.java.PublicClient.main(PublicClient.java:23)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:585)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.openConnection(HttpHelper.java:110)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpGet(HttpHelper.java:43)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpGet(HttpHelper.java:38)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.MexParser.getWsTrustEndpointFromMexEndpoint(MexParser.java:87)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.processPasswordGrant(AuthenticationContext.java:852)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$0(AuthenticationContext.java:839)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:129)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have correctly specified my client ID, username and password. Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Peter Pan - MSFT, I was able to get this issue resolved. The problem was I was using a Microsoft account and not a service account. After I setup a service account, I was able to get the sample working.

In order to setup a service account, open [the azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/?r=1), go to all services, open subscriptions, select your subscription, scroll down and click on "Roles" and click on "Reader" (or any other category which you like but make sure it has proper access priviliges) and click on "+" to add a new user which should not be a microsoft user.

Comment: I am unsure about what you mean that the user shouldn't be a Microsoft user. It seems like the only choice is to use a user in the company.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduce your issue. The problem is that the sample PublicClient.java is a separate Maven project with Microsoft AAD Library for Java.

To resolve this issue, you need to import the sample project alone to Eclipse as the follows.

[image]

Then you run the maven install to install all depencies for the sample project and execute it. It will works without exception.

Comment: I imported the sample PublicClient as a separate maven project ([screenshot](http://imgur.com/3nmqtNx)) and ran `mvn install` on the sample's directory but still the same error.

Comment: Could you describe the details or snapshoot the error exception？

Comment: Exactly the same exception as posted on the question.

Comment: @i08in The sample program is no problem. I reproduced the same issue by runing the sample. I found out that the cause of the exception issue is your account not in Azure AD of your created Application(client ID). I suggest to check accounts of your Azure AD on Azure Portal again.

Comment: Thanks for that investigation. Is there any simple beginner's documentation that i can follow for setting up my account properly from scratch?

Comment: @i08in Refer to the link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-developers-guide/#how-tos, it list some "How to do" topic documents to introduce using AAD. If you want to develop for Application integration with AAD, you can refer to the topic https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn308590.aspx.